# I am not able to configure data source in jboss as7

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc, jboss

When I right click on project -> Resolve datasource problem -> add connection -> test connection

I found this error

"Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)) "

I have checked all the configurations regarding the same in standalone.xml, even googled a lot but couldn't find required solution.

I would be greatfull if anyone will give a try.

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:`service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.cfpDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."cfp-ejbs.jar#cfpPU"] 

18:01:58,430 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"cfp-ejbs.jar#cfpPU\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.cfpDSMissing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"cfp-ejbs.jar#cfpPU\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.cfpDS]"]}}}
```

Comment: can you share the stacktracke of the deployment error? the one you showed does not show the cause of failure..

Comment: @mendieta You can view my error stacktrace in the following notepad file[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B95JPHf0h0NoSXdweUlfa3JuMHc/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Ok, looks like something is wrong with the datasource used by your cfpPU persistent unit. Can you share your persistence.xml and your datasource config?

Comment: @mendieta this is my datasource config file [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B95JPHf0h0NoMm50Umt3Zy1TNEE/view?usp=sharing] and this one is my persisitence.xml [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B95JPHf0h0NoNVg1OWtFdWFzLXc/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: @mendieta I have found the error which was I was using incorrect jndi-name. Thanks a lot for giving me your precious time.

Comment: I thought the problem was the way you were defining your datasource. I don´t think jboss 7 uses the local-tx-datasource form.. I would check out this link http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/migrate-jboss-datasources-howto
Good job spotting that jndi name!